# Debugging some code that is not printing any stack trace

Tags: java, debugging

So I am debugging someone else's customized code used in a Java based enterprise software. As per his documentation, a specific file has the customization I am looking into. I deployed all customized files on the test server and now the browser window crashes as soon as it starts to render data using that code. No stack trace gets printed out. The customized code in question is not actually causing the issue. The issues is caused by some other code that uses the data returned from this piece of code. The puzzle for me is that I don't really know where the data is being returned to, and any error being thrown is not printed out. Is there anything I can do to figure out what file uses the data returned by this customized code?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force: Tell debugger to break on all exceptions.

E.g. in Eclipse, select menu "Run" > "Add Java Exception Breakpoint...", type `Exception` and select the `java.lang.Exception`, check both "Suspend on caught exceptions" and "Suspend on uncaught exceptions", and click "OK". In the "Breakpoints" view, select the new `Exception` breakpoint and check "Subclasses of this exception".

This is break on *any* thrown `Exception` (not `Error`). You may see a lot of false positives, which is why I call this the "brute force" method.

Change to `Throwable` if you want to catch `Error` too.